# Stream the output of a void function using printf()

Tags: c, file, file-io, stream, printf

I want to store the output of a function (`matrix_output_printf()`) printing the following output (a matrix):

```
0   1   2   
1   2   3   
2   3   4
```

I would like to save this output in a text file.

In a first attempt, I modified the original in `matrix_output_fprintf()` so that it stores the output continuously using `fprintf()`. I indeed stores the output but the code of `matrix_output_printf()` has been changed

However, I would like not to modify `matrix_output_printf()` as, let's say, it is part of a package and want to test it without modifiying it.
Is there a way to store (using C and not bash) the output of `matrix_output_printf()` from outside the function (or without using `fprintf()`?

The content of **file.txt** is the following:

```
0   1   2   
1   2   3   
2   3   4
```

Here is the code:

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matrix_output();

void matrix_output_printf(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      printf("%d\t", i+j);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void matrix_output_fprintf(){
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
  fclose(fp);
  fp = fopen("file.txt", "ab");
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      fprintf(fp, "%d\t", i+j);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
  }
  fclose(fp);
}


int main ()
{
  matrix_output_printf();
  matrix_output_fprintf();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "capture the output" mean?  Do you want it in a string?  If so, you can use `sprintf`.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Can you try rephrasing the question?

Comment: yes probably. But I would like that `matrix_output_printf()` remains unchanged. Is it possible with `sprintf`?

Comment: Without changing the function, the closest thing you can do is close stdout and open a separate file, dup-ing it to file descriptor 1.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I edited the question and tried to make it more clear

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you propose @dbush?

Comment: Passing a `FILE *` to the function for it to use `fprintf` is a much more versatile approach. Once you redirect `stdout` to a file with `freopen`, it is quite difficult to restore the previous stream.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Could you also maybe provide an example?

Comment: You could also redirect the output of stdout without having to change anything in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to redirect `stdout` to a file, you can do that with the `freopen` function:

```
freopen("file.txt", "wb", stdout);
```

After this call, any write to `stdout` will write to the file "file.txt".

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @dbush. I allowed myself to put the entire file into the question as an edit (if it is correct, at least it worked for me). one question though: you do not need to close the file with`freopen()` (as for example with `fopen()` and `fclose()`?

Comment: @ecjb Yes, you'll need to use `fclose` at some point.

Comment: Ok: in the edit I provided should I use `fclose()` or `fclose("file.txt")` or something else?

Comment: @ecjb It's `stdout` that was reopened, so you would `fclose(stdout)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a POSIX-compliant system, you can use the `dup2` system call.

From the man page:

> The dup() system call allocates a new file descriptor that refers
> to the same open file description as the descriptor oldfd.
>
> .....The dup2() system call performs the same task as dup(), but
> instead of using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor, it
> uses the file descriptor number specified in newfd.  In other
> words, the file descriptor newfd is adjusted so that it now
> refers to the same open file description as oldfd.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FILE_NAME "file.txt"

int main (void)
{
        int fd = open (FILE_NAME, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
        if (fd == -1) {
                perror ("open()");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        /* We want stdout to point to this file */
        int rv = 0;

        do {
            rv = dup2 (fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        } while ((rv == -1) && (errno == EINTR));

        if (rv == -1) {
                close (fd);
                perror ("dup2()");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        /* We no longer need the original file descriptor */
        close (fd);

        /* Now writing to STDOUT_FILENO == FILE.TXT_FILENO */
        printf ("You're my sunshine now.\n");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Something to note:

> If the file descriptor newfd was previously open, it is closed
> before being reused; the close is performed silently (i.e., any
> errors during the close are not reported by dup2()).

So we don't need to close `STDOUT_FILENO` after the call to `dup2()`. It is done for us automatically.

---

But the above function is only defined in the POSIX standard, not the C standard. So we can take another route (one already mentioned). You can redirect the `stdout` to `file.txt` with `freopen`.

From the man page:

> The freopen() function shall first attempt to flush the stream
> associated with stream as if by a call to fflush(stream).
> Failure to flush the stream successfully shall be ignored. If
> pathname is not a null pointer, freopen() shall close any file
> descriptor associated with stream.  Failure to close the file
> descriptor successfully shall be ignored.  The error and end-of-
> file indicators for the stream shall be cleared.
> The freopen() function shall open the file whose pathname is the
> string pointed to by pathname and associate the stream pointed to
> by stream with it. The mode argument shall be used just as in
> fopen().
>
> The original stream shall be closed regardless of whether the
> subsequent open succeeds.

```
#define FILE_NAME "file.txt"

/* Upon successful completion, freopen() shall return the
*  value of stream.  Otherwise, a null pointer shall be returned,
*  and errno shall be set to indicate the error.
*/
FILE *fp = freopen (FILE_NAME, "w", stdout);
if (!fp) {
    /* freopen() failed. Handle error here. */
    ....
}
```

Note that this has the disadvantage that there's generally no way to undo it, and as @chqrlie said in the comments: *"Passing a `FILE *` to the function for it to use `fprintf()` is a much more versatile approach."*

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is the complete working code which worked for me, thanks to the answer of @dbush:

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matrix_output();

void matrix_output_printf(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      printf("%d\t", i+j);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main ()
{ 
  freopen("file.txt", "wb", stdout);
  matrix_output_printf();
  fclose(stdout);
  return 0;
}
```